# Spring MVC: No mapping in DispatcherServlet with name mvc-dispatcher

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and when i try to access my application using below URL i am getting error message -**No mapping in DispatcherServlet with name mvc-dispatcher**

```
http://localhost:8090/springexample/helloWorld
```

1.web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

2.mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**3.HelloWorldController**

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String hello(ModelMap model) {

            model.addAttribute("name", "Hello World!");
            return "helloWorld";

        }

    }
```

4.pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and the corresponding namespace declarations in your servlet context.

Without it, a default MVC stack is generated for you which doesn't include your Controllers.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Let me give a try

Comment: Thanks alot it worked...I can't upvote as i don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @PawanSharma You're welcome. You should probably spend a few hours reading the Spring (4) MVC documentation. It is very easy to read and clarifies a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean id="paramResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver" >
    <property name="paramName">
        <value>action</value>
    </property>  
</bean>
<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="DemoPackages.Controller" >
    <property name="methodNameResolver">
        <ref bean="paramResolver"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```